# On boundedness of sequence of operators in vN algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $x_{n}$ be a sequence of operators in vN algebra $M$, $\Omega$ is a cyclic vector for $M$, if $x_{n}\Omega$ converges in $\mathcal{H}$, can we say there exist a subsequence $\{y_{n}\}$ of $\{x_{n}\}$ are uniformly bounded in operator norm?

Comment: What if $M=B(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$, $\Omega=e_1$ (first basis vector) and $x_n=n\cdot p_n$? (where $p_n$ is the rank one projection onto $\mathbb C e_n$)

Comment: If $M$ is $II_{1}$ factor??

Comment: Any $II_1$ factor contains a copy of $l^\infty$ and Andre's example will still work.

Comment: @NikWeaver Can you please give a tiny bit more detail on what you mean by "my example will still works"... I think of the case of $B(H)$ and the case of a $II_1$ factor as quite different (e.g. if $M$ is $II_1$, then $\Omega$ is often taken to be separating, which is very different from the situation I was considering)

Comment: Sure, start with a projection $0 <p_1 <1$, then find another one $0 < p_2 < 1 - p_1$, etc. This gives you a sequence of mutually orthogonal projections, and if we work in an irrep then any nonzero vector in the range of $p_1$ will be cyclic, and then consider the sequence $(np_n)$ as you suggested. Am I missing something?

Comment: @NikWeaver Ah, I see. :-) Small nitpick: $II_1$ factors don't have irreps (if one restricts attention to normal representations).

Comment: @AndréHenriques: Oh, really?  I didn't know that. I guess it's not a serious problem, as all we really need is a cyclic vector in the range of some nontrivial projection.

Comment: @NikWeaver: The commutant of a $II_1$ factor (in a normal representation) is always a type $II$ factor (either $II_1$ or $II_\infty$). In particular, it can never be $\mathbb C$ as would be the case if the representation were irreducible.

Comment: @AndréHenriques: Oh, of course!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy counterexample:

$M=M_{2}(\mathbb C)$,
$H=\mathbb C^2$,
$\Omega=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$,
$x_n=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & n\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.